# WPF ComboBox and Menus opening in the background

Tags: .net, wpf, menu

In one of my projects, I am facing an issue where the combo box drop menu and the context menus are *sometimes* not visible. By sometimes, I mean that they open up fine in about 80% of the cases, but the same screen, with the same code will have this problem mysteriously 20% of the times.

When I observed one of the ModalPopup windows, it seems like the menus open beneath the popup window. The obvious question that came to my mind was z-index. But if that really was the issue, wouldn't this happen always?

Is this a known issue with WPF? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been a couple issues related to this:

WPF4 bug report:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/465964/wpf-combobox-dropdown-list-appears-behind-the-form-when-allowstransparency-true

Possible hotfix:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943326